# What's the difference between these ordered factors?

Tags: r, ordinal-data

```
str(test)
'data.frame':   767 obs. of  2 variables:
$ datefield: Ord.factor w/ 59 levels "1984-04-01"<"1984-07-01"<..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10  
    $ somevar : num  43.7 55.6 43.5 54.1 42.8 ...

> str(Italy)
'data.frame':   1008 obs. of  2 variables:
$ year: Ord.factor w/ 48 levels "1951"<"1952"<..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
    $ gdp : num  8.56 12.26 9.59 8.12 5.54 ...
```

I turned the datefield into an ordered factor because I try to reproduce an example with own data. Now I wonder what the difference between is, or put it differently, what does 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10  mean opposed to 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you convert a variable to a factor variable using the `factor` function (without using special arguments) the original values are substituted with the codes 1, 2, 3 ..., and the original values are assigned to these codes as labels. See `?factor`.

Your 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 means that first 10 the values of datefield were the smallest values of the datefield variable, and each of them was unique (only appearing once).
The 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 means that the first 10 values of year was 1951, and that 1951 was the lowest value of the year variable.